# mpdf - nested divs and positioning

Tags: php, pdf, mpdf

I have 2 divs like the following:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z5224/)

You can they render, one on top of each other, which is fine.

The problem is the positioning within the PDF.

I have tried in the style `position:absolute;top:100px` etc, but for some reason I cannot move the div when rendering using `mPDF`. none of the `top, left, right or bottom` positioning seem to work. Is this a limitation in mDF?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well as its a PDF it doesnt work in pixels its in mm but other than that it should work, have a look through the examples that come with it, theres some really good examples of achienving different stuff in CSS

Comment: I have changed the positioning to use `mm` but that also hasn't changed the output

Comment: ah well with mpdf you should have got an examples folder with like 30+ examples. im pretty sure one of the handles overlapping divs, just go through them, sorry can't remember the example number. won't take long to quick load each one in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Taken directly from the mpdf site.

> Blocks which are defined as position:absolute, position:fixed or
>   float:xxx are only partially supported.

http://mpdf.bpm1.com/index.php?page=Limitations